# Call node api from mobile phone while developing flutter app

Tags: node.js, api, flutter, http, localhost

I am developing a chat application. I connect my mobile phone for testing/debugging while developing. But I can't call backend node API from my mobile phone and have to use an emulator to do so and the emulator works very slow on my laptop. Is there any way I could call the API from my connected mobile itself while developing?

```
static const BaseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";
```

I also tried by giving ip address wherein both pc and my mobile phone are in the same network as below-

```
  static const BaseUrl = "http://ipv4 address:8000/";
```

Is there any way I can test my app while developing through connected mobile phone and call backend node api?

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Command Prompt or whatever console you have. I am using windows, so I would open up the CMD and type in IPconfig. Go to where you see "IPv4 Address", and copy the numbers that you see there. THAT will be what you will need to use in order to get access to your server. Make sure that your phone and computer(or whatever you are running the server on) is on the same WIFI, or else this will not work.

Comment: The second URL that I have above is from the ipv4 address that we get on cmd. It didn't work for me. Is there anything else I am missing? Both the devices are connected to the same network.

Comment: Did you add the necessary permissions to your AndroidManifest file so that you can make calls to the internet?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you are using port 3000 instead of 8000. If this was not intentional, make sure to always use the same port that you started the server on for all calls to your server.

Comment: Ya, I had kept it 3000 before. Now I kept my ipv4 address with port 8000 at the backend and was calling like the 2nd URL above from flutter. But it still didn't work. I also added rule in firewall settings to allow 8000 port.